# NPE on getId after convert from Dto to Entity (both mapstruct and modelmapper)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mapstruct, converters, modelmapper

I need some help on this :)

I have as Abstract model that provide ID, creation time and update time to every entity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator = "native")
@Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
protected Long id;

@Column(updatable = false)
@CreationTimestamp
protected Timestamp creationTime;

@UpdateTimestamp
protected Timestamp updateTime;

//getters and setters
```

entity sample:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CUSTOMERS", uniqueConstraints={@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"fiscalNumber" , "phoneNumber", "email"})})
public class Customer extends AbstractModel {

//other properties
//getters and setters
}
```

controller:

```
public String saveCustomer(@Valid @ModelAttribute("customer") CustomerDto customerDto, BindingResult result, Model model) {

...

    customerService.save(customerMapper.toModel(customerDto));
    model.addAttribute("customer", customerDto);
    return "redirect:/customer/list";
}
```

Dao implementation:

```
public Customer save(Customer model) ... {

        if (model.getId() == null) {
            return (Customer) session.merge(model);
        }
...
}
```

what happens is every time that I try to get Id using model.getId, I got a nullPointerException, even if I use Objects.isNull(model.getId()), or wrap it on a Optional

if I try the same but to get creationTime (model.getCreationTime()) it works as expected.

extra information:
NPE only appear after convert modelDto(customerDto) to model(customer) and only for Id. At this moment I'm using modelmapper but I've also tried with mapstruct and I have the same error. I've also tried various types of convert Strategies.

Thanks for your attention :)

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace of the NPE? thanks

Comment: hi, I was using Long (object) in my entity and long (primitive) in my get method :)